# Databricks job failure

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, databricks

I have a job in azure Databricks that is giving me time out error when it save data in azure datalake. The job reads new data from path1. Make some queries to compare data and get last update, compare this filtered new data with historic data to get more recent data and save the result in datalake. This job runs daily so data is saved in datalake partitioned by the date it has been processed.

Error is:

```
Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o3507.parquet.
: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted.
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$.write(FileFormatWriter.scala:230)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.InsertIntoHadoopFsRelationCommand.run(InsertIntoHadoopFsRelationCommand.scala:192)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.DataWritingCommandExec.sideEffectResult$lzycompute(commands.scala:116)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.DataWritingCommandExec.sideEffectResult(commands.scala:114)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.DataWritingCommandExec.doExecute(commands.scala:139)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.$anonfun$execute$1(SparkPlan.scala:200)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.$anonfun$executeQuery$3(SparkPlan.scala:252)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:165)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.executeQuery(SparkPlan.scala:248)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.execute(SparkPlan.scala:192)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.toRdd$lzycompute(QueryExecution.scala:158)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.toRdd(QueryExecution.scala:157)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.$anonfun$runCommand$1(DataFrameWriter.scala:999)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.$anonfun$withCustomExecutionEnv$5(SQLExecution.scala:142)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withSQLConfPropagated(SQLExecution.scala:275)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.$anonfun$withCustomExecutionEnv$1(SQLExecution.scala:127)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession.withActive(SparkSession.scala:845)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withCustomExecutionEnv(SQLExecution.scala:103)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withNewExecutionId(SQLExecution.scala:225)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.runCommand(DataFrameWriter.scala:999)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.saveToV1Source(DataFrameWriter.scala:437)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.save(DataFrameWriter.scala:421)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.save(DataFrameWriter.scala:294)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.parquet(DataFrameWriter.scala:884)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:244)
    at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:380)
    at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:295)
    at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
    at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
    at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:251)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 13 in stage 228.0 failed 4 times, most recent failure: Lost task 13.3 in stage 228.0 (TID 9103, 10.139.64.9, executor 14): ExecutorLostFailure (executor 14 exited caused by one of the running tasks) Reason: Executor heartbeat timed out after 157722 ms
Driver stacktrace:
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.failJobAndIndependentStages(DAGScheduler.scala:2564)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.$anonfun$abortStage$2(DAGScheduler.scala:2511)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.$anonfun$abortStage$2$adapted(DAGScheduler.scala:2505)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:62)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray.foreach$(ResizableArray.scala:55)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:49)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.abortStage(DAGScheduler.scala:2505)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1(DAGScheduler.scala:1197)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1$adapted(DAGScheduler.scala:1197)
    at scala.Option.foreach(Option.scala:407)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.handleTaskSetFailed(DAGScheduler.scala:1197)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.doOnReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:2766)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:2713)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:2701)
    at org.apache.spark.util.EventLoop$$anon$1.run(EventLoop.scala:49)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.runJob(DAGScheduler.scala:983)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2339)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$.write(FileFormatWriter.scala:199)
    ... 34 more
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi I think it's a cache problem, try adding .cache() at the end of your read and write fuction, i.e

```
df = context.read.csv('mycsv.csv').cache()
or
df.write.csv('mycsv.csv').cache()
```

This should resolved the issue, let me know if this helps :) - Paula